# Basic 2 image slideshow in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a basic jquery 2 image slideshow. I don't want the images to fade into eachother, they should just simply change every second. 
In the jquery code I have below, the code includes fading. What would be the correct code without fading?

```
<div id="manwrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="images/index-man.png" width="500" height="788" alt="SS Image" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/index-man2.png" width="500" height="788" alt="SS Image" />
    </div>
</div>
<!--end manwrapper-->
```

## CSS

```
#container #manwrapper {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -280px;
    z-index: 3;
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:788px;
}
#container #manwrapper > div {
    position:absolute;
}
```

## JavaScript

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#manwrapper > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#manwrapper');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: have you tried removing the lines `.fadeOut(1000)` and `.fadeIn(1000)` ?

Comment: yes, that does do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'fadeOut(1000)` and `.fadeIn(1000)`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfh5S/1/)

Comment: @ahul maindargi,@Derek Henderson the images sort of fade into eachother when using this code, and the bottom left hand corner of the image moves up to the center in an intersting sort of way. Simply removing the lines .fadeout(1000) and .fadein(1000) works best.

Comment: Yes, was in the process of creating a fiddle when you left your comment.  I saw this in the fiddle and changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#manwrapper > div:first')
    .hide(1000)
    .next()
    .show(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#manwrapper');
},  3000);
```